Why do we normalize means to 0?
I was wondering why normalization (e.g. for PCA) generally brings the means to 0. I understand the idea behind normalizing --- every variable would contribute the same, regardless of their differences in range --- but I cannot see why it is be important to normalize to 0. Wouldn't it be enough to normalize to another common value (say, every variable has a mean of 1 or 10)?
Thanks!

You usually want to centre PCA.   For some other calculations, it may make little difference but can still aid interpretation; for others it may be unhelpful in interpretation ( such as $0-1$ dummy variables)

Because it makes stuff easier.
If mean is zero, variance is simply $E[X^2]$.
